# C++ check cin for valid data not working

Tags: c++, char, cin

I am doing an assignment for school and I am using an array filled with the ICAO words alphabet. The user enters a letter and then the program displays what ICAO word goes with the letter provided. I am using an index variable to get the ICAO word from the ICAO array. However I need to check that the user only enters a single letter to go into the char input variable. How can I do this? Below is what I have but is not working correctly. It reads the first letter and spits out the result from the first letter, then closes right away.

```
int main()
string icao[26] = 
"Alpha",
 "Bravo",
 "Charlie",
 "Delta",
 "Echo",
 "Foxtrot",
 "Golf",
 "Hotel",
 "India",
 "Juliet",
 "Kilo",
 "Lima",
 "Mike",
 "November",
 "Oscar",
 "Papa",
 "Quebec",
 "Romeo",
 "Sierra",
 "Tango",
 "Uniform",
 "Victor",
 "Whiskey",
 "X-ray",
 "Yankee",
 "Zulu"
};
int index;
char i;
cout << "Enter a letter from A-Z to get the ICAO word for that letter: ";
while(!(cin >> i))
{
    cout << "Please enter a single letter from A-Z: ";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(1000,'\n');
}
i = toupper(i);
index = int(i)-65;
cout << "The ICAO word for " << i << " is " << icao[index] << ".\n";

cin.get();
cin.get();
return 0;
```

}

***I figured it out from a little of each of the answers. The solution is below:***

```
int main()

//store all the ICAO words in an array
string icao[26] = 
{"Alpha",
 "Bravo",
 "Charlie",
 "Delta",
 "Echo",
 "Foxtrot",
 "Golf",
 "Hotel",
 "India",
 "Juliet",
 "Kilo",
 "Lima",
 "Mike",
 "November",
 "Oscar",
 "Papa",
 "Quebec",
 "Romeo",
 "Sierra",
 "Tango",
 "Uniform",
 "Victor",
 "Whiskey",
 "X-ray",
 "Yankee",
 "Zulu"
};
int index;
string input = "";
cout << "Enter a letter from A-Z to get the ICAO word for that letter: ";

// get the input from the user
cin >> input;
//get the first character the user entered in case the user entered more than one character
char input1 = input.at(0);
//if the first character is not a letter, tell the user to enter a letter
while (!isalpha(input1))
{
    cout << "Please enter a letter from A-Z: ";
    cin >> input;
    input1 = input.at(0);
    cin.clear();
}
//capitalize the input to match the internal integer for the characters
input1 = toupper(input1);
index = int(input1)-65;
cout << "The ICAO word for " << input1 << " is " << icao[index] << ".\n";

cin.get();
cin.get();
return 0;
```

Comment: You need to put some bounds checking in place on the index lest you try to use an index that may be out of bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your check for

```
while( !cin )
```

checks if the stream has failed. End-Of-File or some other cause. What you want to accomplish is trickier. Maybe you could do a getline( cin, string ) to check if the user only input one character and then hit return.

```
string input;
getline( cin, input );
if ( input.size() == 1 && *input.c_str()>='A' && *input.c_str()<='Z' )
```

Or something to that effect. Note that the condition states the opposite of what I think your intentions were with your while statement.

Comment: Solely checking the state of the stream in the while condition is nearly always wrong. while( !(cin >> i )) is a much better technique. It also mirrors all imperative languages that pretend files are streams.

Comment: In this case the checking of failbit|badbit is erroneous. I did not find it in the scope of the question necessary to explain the state of fail|bad|eof. And yes while( !(cin >> i )) would be the way to go if this was the case

Answer (score 1):

OK.

so std::cin is buffered so you probably need to type:  "a<enter>" to make it work.
This works for me:

```
cin >> i:  reads the 'a' character.  
cin.get(): reads the enter character.
cin.get(): Waits for me to hit enter a second time before quitting.
```

Note: If I type "1<enter>" It works but I get a segmentation fault when trying to access the array.